# How can I avoid the repeated isValid in this jQuery validate case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a field, my main targets are:

1. when a user lands on the page, no validations
2. validation starts on a user clicks the Name Query field, and it validates on both key up and focus out
3. Field is also validated on form submission: if field is invalid, clicking the submit button should do nothing but showing the validation message; form will only be submitted when the field is valid.

Here is a snippet I came up with:

```js
var myForm = $("#myform"),
    nameQuery = $("#NameQuery");

myForm.validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query"
  }
});

nameQuery.on("focusout keyup submit", function() {
  var isValid = myForm.valid();
  if (!isValid) {
    nameQuery.addClass("alert-text");
  }
  else {
    nameQuery.removeClass("alert-text");
  };
});

nameQuery.on("submit", function() {
  var isValid = myForm.valid();
  if (isValid) {
    $("p").html("Form sumitted");
  }
  else {
    $("p").empty();
  };
});
```

```css
.alert-text {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post">
  <label for="NameQuery">Name Query: </label>
  <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
  <p></p>
</form>
```

A few problems:

1. I used `var isValid = myForm.valid();` twice, seems a bit repeated but I could not think of a more concise way?
2. if field is valid, clicking the submit button leads to everything disappears?
3. can my snippet improve in any ways?

**EDIT**: by saying code repeated and being more concise I meant can these 2 parts be merged into 1 part:

```
nameQuery.on("focusout keyup submit", function() {
  var isValid = myForm.valid();
  if (!isValid) {
    nameQuery.addClass("alert-text");
  }
  else {
    nameQuery.removeClass("alert-text");
  };
});
```

and

```
nameQuery.on("submit", function() {
  var isValid = myForm.valid();
  if (isValid) {
    $("p").html("Form sumitted");
  }
  else {
    $("p").empty();
  };
});
```

They operate on the same element and the logic inside looks similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely misunderstanding what this plugin can do for you...

> when a user lands on the page, no validations

This is already the default behavior of this plugin.  Nothing happens when the page loads except for plugin initialization, which the user does not see.

> validation starts on a user clicks the Name Query field, and it validates on both key up and focus out

This is called "eager" validation and the plugin is "lazy" by default.  There is a simple way to implement "eager" without any external event handlers.

> Field is also validated on form submission: if field is invalid, clicking the submit button should do nothing but showing the validation message; form will only be submitted when the field is valid.

That's exactly how this plugin works when it's used correctly.

> by saying code repeated and being more concise I meant can these 2 parts be merged into 1 part:

No, these two parts should just be removed entirely.  They are superfluous since the plugin already gives you these options.

---

[You really need to review the docs to understand everything here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).  There is rarely a case where you need external event handler functions, so if you do, it starts getting way more complicated than it needs to be.  At that point you might as well just write your own custom validation function from scratch.

This plugin has the `submitHandler` for custom code when form is valid and being submitted, the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` options for custom code when these actions occur, plus many, many other options and configurations.

For the red dotted line around the input, the default class is `error`, so just target this class with your CSS.

```
input.error {
    /* this targets the input element with a pending validation error */
    border: 1px dashed red;
}

label.error [
    /* this targets the validation error message */
}
```

If you really need to change the name of the default class, then use the `errorClass` option.

Only use the `submitHandler` if you want additional custom code upon submission.  Example:  when submitting via ajax.  Otherwise, for regular submit, the `submitHandler` can be left out and the default behavior of the plugin will be to simply submit the form when it is valid.

Use the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` for custom code on these actions.  If you want more eager validation like validation before the initial submission attempt, then you can put the custom code here to force that.  Otherwise, remove these two options and try it again.  Your form only has one input so it may not matter at all since validation will kick in if they type into the field and backspace.  Eager vs. Lazy is more of an issue when the user tabs through multiple inputs without typing anything.  Not really the case here.

```js
var myForm    = $("#myform");

// nameQuery = $("#NameQuery"); // NOT needed here.  
/* Plugin uses NAME attribute only, not ID and not assigned variables */

myForm.validate({
    rules: {
        NameQuery: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        NameQuery: "Please fill in name query"
    },
    onkeyup: function(element) {
        this.element(element);  // <- force "eager validation"
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        this.element(element);  // <- force "eager validation"
    },
    // errorClass: "alert-text", // default is "error" - just use CSS
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("p").html("Form submitted"); // for demo
        // form.submit(); // default line, un-comment to submit when valid or leave out entire submitHandler to submit when valid
    }
});
```

```css
input.error {
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post">
    <label for="NameQuery">Name Query: </label>
    <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    <p></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers:
1)If it seems repetitive `var isValid = myForm.valid();` then use `if(myForm.valid())` this.
2)Everything disappears because you are calling submit function on input box instead of form and the default form submit behavior is refresh.
   Try the below code

```js
  var myForm = $("#myform"),
    nameQuery = $("#NameQuery");

myForm.validate({
  rules: {
    NameQuery: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    NameQuery: "Please fill in name query"
  }
});

nameQuery.on("focusout keyup submit", function() {
  if (!myForm.valid()) {
    nameQuery.addClass("alert-text");
  }
  else {
    nameQuery.removeClass("alert-text");
  };
});

myForm.on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (myForm.valid()) {
    $("p").html("Form submitted");
  }
  else {
    $("p").empty();
  };
});
```

```css
.alert-text {
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>


<form id="myform" method="post">
  <label for="NameQuery">Name Query: </label>
  <input type="text" id="NameQuery" name="NameQuery">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
  <p></p>
</form>
```

3)I have improved it to a bit. You can see above

Comment: The OP needs to be shown how to properly use this plugin.  The external event handlers are messy, unnecessary, and interfere with the plugin, and therefore should have been removed entirely and replaced with the proper options provided by the plugin.